# Correct regex pattern for targeting specific sectors within UK Postcode

Tags: regex

What is the correct way to only target LA7, LA8, LA9, LA11, LA12, LA21, LA22, LA23, CA10, CA11 and CA12.

I have done the pattern seperately but I imagine this is not the most efficient or correct way to do it.

`/^(LA[7-9A-Z]? ?\d[0-9A-Z]{2}|LA[11-12A-Z]? ?\d[0-9A-Z]{2}|LA[21-23A-Z]? ?\d[0-9A-Z]{2}|CA[10-12A-Z]? ?\d[0-9A-Z]{2})$/`

Comment: Looks like listing the possibilities you want to match is shorter than the corresponding regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the point is to only match these specific codes as standalone strings, you can use

```
^(?:LA(?:2[123]|1[12]|[789])|CA1[012])$
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fc9yeK/1).

To match them in a longer text, you can use a regex variation with word boundaries:

```
\b(?:LA(?:2[123]|1[12]|[789])|CA1[012])\b
```

*Details*:

- `^` - start of a string
- `(?:LA(?:2[123]|1[12]|[789])|CA1[012])`  - either of the two alternatives:

  - `LA(?:2[123]|1[12]|[789])` - `LA` and then either `2` followed with `1`, `2` or `3`, or `1` followed with `1` or `2`, or `7`, `8` or `9`
  - `|` - or
  - `CA1[012]`  - `CA1` and then `0`, or `1`, or `2`
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: I'm using this at the moment /^(LA(7|8|9|11|12|21|22|23)? ?\d[0-9A-Z]{2}|CA[10-12]? ?\d[0-9A-Z]{2})$/ do you know why 'LA 3HD' is registering as valid syntax? It should require a number after the 'LA' eg: 'LA7 3HD' do you know how I do that?

Comment: @Third_Hyperion You made the number pattern optional, see the `?` at the end of the  `(7|8|9|11|12|21|22|23)?`.

Comment: Ah! I thought the `? ?` was making the space between the postcode optional? eg: LA7 3HD / LA73HD

Comment: @Third_Hyperion No need to repeat the right part, use `^(?:CA1[0-2]|LA(?:7|8|9|11|12|21|22|23)) ?\d[0-9A-Z]{2}$`. Note that `[10-12]` = `[012]` = `[0-2]`, it matches `0`, `1` or `2`. To match `10`, `11` or `12`, you need `1[0-2]`

Comment: Thank you so much. I have a seperate field where I am matching different postcodes, please could you help me with the syntax on that one? I currently have - `^(M(24|25|8|9|45|6|7|27)? ?\d[0-9A-Z]{2})$` I need it to match against M25, M24, M8, M9, M45, M6, M7 and M27

Comment: is this correct - `^(?:M(?:24|25|8|9|45|6|7|27)) ?\d[0-9A-Z]{2}$`

Comment: @Third_Hyperion I'd write it as `^M(?:[6-9]|2[457]|45) ?\d[0-9A-Z]{2}$`

Comment: @Third_Hyperion So, is the question аnswеrеd?